# Effect of having false confidence because of confusion of familiarity and knowledge

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, terminology

What is the name of the effect which causes one to skip information that feel familiar during learning due to the confusion of familiarity and knowledge?

Comment: Cognitive ease / fluency?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg Thanks, that's a good box but I had a feeling I've heard a term specific for what I've described

Answer (score 2):

Change blindness: failure to notice large changes to the visual scene [1].

If you are interested in familiarity change blindness I suggest [this article](https://curve.carleton.ca/system/files/etd/f85c76cc-3b92-4830-b0cf-b379ef90dbc0/etd_pdf/5d205f7711491500575676969c138324/tovey-seeingchangeshowfamiliarityaltersourperception.pdf) [2].

Reference:

[1] Simons, D. J., & Levin, D. T. (1997). Change blindness. Trends in cognitive sciences, 1(7), 261-267.

[2] Tovey, M., & Herdman, C. M. (2014). Seeing changes: How familiarity alters our perception of change. Visual Cognition, 22(2), 214-238.